# Move files based on certain text in filename to specified folders in focused window

Tags: python-3.x, applescript

I've found similar requests but they don't quite fit my requirement. I've exhausted my searching and I've exhausted my limited skills.

Daily I create multiple new software projects creating the following folder structure:

```
"FOLDER 1" (root) 
  "Subfolder 1"
    "subfolder 2" (inside subfolder 1).
```

Ive tried working with below but ideally i would like it to search for files with "quad bus" in the name and move those files.

tell application "Finder"

```
repeat with this_item in (selection of (folder of window 1))
    
    move this_item to parent of parent of this_item
    
end repeat
```

end tell

I basically need to MOVE files added to **subfolder 2** containing the word **Quad Bus** into the folder named to **FOLDER 1**.

The challenge I have is I can't specify the source and dest paths in the script so it would have to be a service that is run to execute the task in the focused or front finder window. Applescript seems to be the obvious choice but I've tried Python also.

Comment: Do you have an incomplete script that you can post? Something that works partially that we can add to? The difficulty is that your request isn't as clear to us as it probably is to you; at least, I can't quite visualize your workflow. This isn't difficult, but I don't want to waste time writing the wrong script first.

Comment: Are you talking about something like attaching a folder action to `subfolder 2` that moves a matching file to the parent folder of its parent folder?

Comment: @TedWrigley thanks i've edited the post to include a basic applescript but i ideally want it to search for the name in the focused window. Thanks again

Comment: @red_menace - The problem i have with that is these folders are created at the begining of each project so wouldnt be ideal to add a folder action to them i think?

Answer (score 1):

The following Automator Service should get the basics for you, though I'm sure it could be improved. Open Automator, create a new Service, and set it up as shown in this image:

[image: workflow image]

This uses two variables, which I called (with great creativity) `ChosenFolder` and `DestinationFolder`. You don't need to set values for them in Automator; values will be provided at runtime. Note that the fifth action (`Get Value Of Variable`) is set to ignore the input from the previous action. If you miss that break, Automator will throw an error, since it will add the destination folder into the list of items that need to be moved.